# Login and Registration with Java Servlets

Tags: sql, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have asked a question similar to this in the past but this is a slightly different issue.  I am implementing a Web Application using Java Servlets.  I'm having a problem with login and registration functionality.  In my earlier question I had problems with the database connectivity.  I have since solved that problem and am now having problems getting the application to redirect to the correct page upon a successful login or registration of a new user.  Here is the code for the Login servlet:

```
package hw5package;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author Tyler
 */
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP
 * <code>GET</code> and
 * <code>POST</code> methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@cci-ora02.uncc.edu:1521:class";
        String username = "teverha4";
        String password = "qwe123";

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>ITIS 4166 Project</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<div align='center'>");
        out.println("<h1>ITIS 4166 Project - Login Page</h1>");
        out.println("<h2>by: Tyler Everhart</h2>");

        out.println("<br />");
        out.println("<br />");
        out.println("<br />");
        out.println("<br />");

        out.println("<table width='20%' border='1' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1'>");
        out.println("<form id='loginForm' name='loginForm' method='POST'>");
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='006F13' align='left' colspan='2'><b>Login</b></td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551' align='left'>Username:</td>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551'>");
        out.println("<input type='text' name='username' id='username' />");
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        String passUsername = request.getParameter("username");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551' align='left'>Password:</td>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551'>");
        out.println("<input type='password' name='pwd' id='pwd' />");
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        String passPwd = request.getParameter("pwd");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='006F13' align='center' colspan='2'>");
        out.println("<input type='submit' value='Submit' onclick='loginValidation()' /> ");
        out.println("<input type='reset' value='Reset' />");
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("</form>");
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("<a href='Registration'>New User, Click Here to Register</a>");
        out.println("</div>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

        Class.forName(driver);

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT UserName, PassWord FROM UserLogin";

        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            if ((passUsername.equals(resultSet.getString("UserName")) && passPwd.equals(resultSet.getString("PassWord")))) {
                String sessionID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                session.setAttribute("username", passUsername);
                session.setAttribute("sessionID", sessionID);
                response.sendRedirect("Categories");
            }
            else if (passUsername.equals("") || passPwd.equals("")) {
                out.println("Enter a username and password.");
            }
            else {
                out.println("Either your username or password is incorrect or could not be found.");
                out.println("Please try again, or click the link below to register.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        System.err.println("Error loading driver: " + cnfe);
        out.println("<tr>Error loading driver: " + cnfe + "</tr>");
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.err.println("Error with connection: " + sqle);
        out.println("<tr>Error with connection: " + sqle + "</tr>");
    }
    finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
}
```

And here is the code for the Registration Servlet:

```
package hw5package;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 *
 * @author Tyler
 */
public class Registration extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP
 * <code>GET</code> and
 * <code>POST</code> methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@cci-ora02.uncc.edu:1521:class";
        String username = "teverha4";
        String password = "qwe123";

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>ITIS 4166 Project</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<div align='center'>");
        out.println("<h1>ITIS 4166 Project - Registration Page</h1>");
        out.println("<h2>by: Tyler Everhart</h2>");

        out.println("<br />");
        out.println("<br />");
        out.println("<br />");
        out.println("<br />");

        out.println("<table width='25%' border='1' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1'>");
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<th bgcolor='006F13' align='left' colspan='2'>Register Account Information</th>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551' align='left'>Requested Username:</td>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551'>");
        out.println("<form id='enterForm' name='enterForm'>");
        out.println("<input type='text' name='requested_username' />");
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        String passUsername = request.getParameter("requested_username");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551' align='left'>Password:</td>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551'>");
        out.println("<input type='password' name='pwd' />");
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        String passPwd = request.getParameter("pwd");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551' align='left'>Confirm Password:</td>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='35D551'>");
        out.println("<input type='password' name='pwd1' />");
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        String passPwd1 = request.getParameter("pwd1");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td bgcolor='006F13' align='center' colspan='2'>");
        out.println("<input name='Submit' type='submit' value='Submit' /> ");
        out.println("<input type='reset' value='Reset' />");
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("</form>");
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</div>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

        Class.forName(driver);

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        if (passPwd.equals("") || passPwd1.equals("")) {
            Integer registerError = Integer.valueOf(1);
            session.setAttribute("registerError", registerError);
            out.println("Please enter a valid password.");
        }
        else if (!passPwd.equals(passPwd1)) {
            Integer registerError = Integer.valueOf(2);
            session.setAttribute("registerError", registerError);
            out.println("Your password and confirm password does not match.");
        }
        else {
            String query2 = "INSERT INTO UserLogin (UserName, PassWord, StockAmt, TechnologyStock, UtilityStock) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query2);
            stmt.setString(1, passUsername);
            stmt.setString(2, passPwd);
            stmt.setInt(3, 0);
            stmt.setInt(4, 0);
            stmt.setInt(5, 0);
            stmt.executeQuery();
            session.setAttribute("sessionUsername", passUsername);
            String sessionID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            Random StockID1 = new Random();
            StockID1.nextInt(10);
            String insertDataSqlMicrosoft = "INSERT INTO StockInfo(StockID, UserID, Type, StockName, Owned, Price, Total) VALUES('" + StockID1 + "','" + passUsername + ",'Technology','Microsoft (MSFT)',0,32.75,0";
            PreparedStatement stmtMicrosoft = connection.prepareStatement(insertDataSqlMicrosoft);
            stmtMicrosoft.executeQuery();

            Random StockID2 = new Random();
            StockID2.nextInt(4);
            String insertDataSqlIntel = "INSERT INTO StockInfo(StockID, UserID, Type, StockName, Owned, Price, Total) VALUES('" + StockID2 + "','" + passUsername + "','Technology','Intel (INTC)',0,26.75,0)";
            PreparedStatement stmtIntel = connection.prepareStatement(insertDataSqlIntel);
            stmtIntel.executeQuery();

            Random StockID3 = new Random();
            StockID3.nextInt(9);
            String insertDataSqlDuke = "INSERT INTO StockInfo(StockID, UserID, Type, StockName, Owned, Price, Total) VALUES('" + StockID3 + "','" + passUsername + "','Utility','Duke Energy (DUK)',0,89.00,0";
            PreparedStatement stmtDuke = connection.prepareStatement(insertDataSqlDuke);
            stmtDuke.executeQuery();

            Random StockID4 = new Random();
            StockID4.nextInt(7);
            String insertDataSqlCable = "INSERT INTO StockInfo(StockID, UserID, Type, StockName, Owned, Price, Total) VALUES('" + StockID4 + "','" + passUsername + "','Utility','Time Warner Cable (TWC)',0,30.00,0)";
            PreparedStatement stmtCable = connection.prepareStatement(insertDataSqlCable);
            stmtCable.executeQuery();

            session.setAttribute("sessionID", sessionID);
            response.sendRedirect("Categories");
        }
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        System.err.println("Error loading driver: " + cnfe);
        out.println("<tr>Error loading driver: " + cnfe + "</tr>");
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.err.println("Error with connection: " + sqle);
        out.println("<tr>Error with connection: " + sqle + "</tr>");
    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP
 * <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
}
```

There is no error message that is being displayed when I try to log in to the system but when I try to register a new user I receive this error message:

Error with connection: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00917: missing comma

The new user is still registered and added to the database but you are not redirected to the next page like you are supposed to be.  I've looked for a while to try to find a way to solve this error but have had zero success so far.  I apologize if this is considered a repost but I swear this is a completely different issue from before.

Comment: You got a `SQLException`, not `ServletException` or any other exception of Java EE / Servlet package. Please do not post SQL problems as Java EE / Servlet problems. This is completely unrelated. You would have exactly the same problem when executing the broken SQL in a plain vanilla Java application with a `main()` method. Learn how to isolate your problem. This will also immediately make your question less bloated and more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
String insertDataSqlMicrosoft = "INSERT INTO StockInfo (StockID, UserID, Type, StockName, Owned, Price, Total) VALUES('" + StockID1 + "','" + passUsername + ",'Technology','Microsoft (MSFT)',0,32.75,0";
```

Note there is no closing parenthesis. This is hard to see given the wall of text you provided. Note this error appears twice, and exactly where you'd expect it: after you construct the sql statement to insert the new user, but before the end of the method - specifically in a subsequent sql statement. Consider the error you received (a SQL error), and you should be able to narrow down on this without presenting all the extraneous code.